# usage of the pattern "A, if not B"

Tags: word-usage

I've seen the pattern `A, if not B` lots of times, though I don't really understand its usage. So, I [googled it a bit](https://www.google.com/search?q=define%20%22if%20not%22&rlz=1C5CHFA_enUS706US706&oq=define%20%22if%20not%22&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l7.4186j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) just now.

Neither [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/if) nor [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/if%20not) gives what I need while [Lexico(Oxford)](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/if) provides a close one.

> hundreds **if not** thousands of germs

Where "if not" means "perhaps even".

Is the following sentence clear and natural? Am I using the pattern `A, if not B` correctly? Is there a term to refer to it?

> **Most, if not all**, of the auxiliary verbs have two possible pronunciations, weak form and stressed/strong form.

In which, A = most and B = all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you're using it correctly. Your interpretation of "most, perhaps even all" is right.

Taking a random phrase from a search for "most, if not all," from Google books:

> Aesthetics are an integral part of most, if not all, human work

That sentence can be paraphrased:
**If** aesthetics are **not** a part of **all** human work, they are still a part of **most** human work.